# Unable to deploy python app on heroku, port binding error

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to deploy the following python app on an heroku server:
https://github.com/PX4/flight_review

The main server script is called ./serve.py, you will find it under:
https://github.com/PX4/flight_review/blob/master/serve.py

It's a tornado web server, but I m not sure on how to configure it, on my local machine I respond to the url http://localhost:5006/

In added a Procfile as follow:

```
web: ./serve.py --host 0.0.0.0:5006
```

and also tried with and without other arguments for the port, and also added a PORT variable into the env variable, but I constantly get the following error:

Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Any idea on what could go wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Following [the documentation about Procfiles](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-format):

You have to just *use* the `$PORT` environment variable, which is set by Heroku when trying to start your dyno.

In your case that would seem to be:

```
web: ./serve.py --host 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Comment: You are right, it now works with web: ./serve.py --port $PORT, but the next error I get is related to the database when trying to post a file  app[web.1]: Error when handling POST data <class 'FileNotFoundError'> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:  Can I post the error here or do I need to ask a new question? thanks!

Comment: that's a separate question IMHO.